# Open Iframe src on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open the iframe's src value in the whole tab/window when I click anywhere on it. How can I do this efficiently and easily? If you are curious, [here is the page](http://searchr.net63.net/results.html?pref=Ask&q=AnInterestingQuery) I am doing it on.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.  It goes to some search page that doesn't seem relevant so I removed it.

Comment: Wha? Ad page? Try this [link](http://searchr.net63.net/results.html?pref=Ask&q=AnInterestingQuery)

Comment: Position a transparent `<div>` over the frame and handle clicks on that.

Comment: I suspect that that might be detected as click-jacking by some anti-malware software though.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy pointed out, you need add a new `<div>` either before or surrounding / containing (i.e. the parent of) the `iframe` which links to the `src` which you given the `iframe`. The `div` would have to be the same height & width of the `iframe` but as long you haven't applied any CSS rules under which this `div` would fall then it should work it out itself and contract to the needed height & width.

Answer (score 0):

Even accessing the iframe document, you have to use some cross domain hack to be able to attach events to the iframde document.

You can have a look at: http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/ to see how you can access the document.

Your best solution, and the simpler is the one suggested by Pointy in the comments. Use a div or transparent image over the iframe and attach the click event to it, grabbing the src attribute via javascript like: `document.getElementById('myFrame').src`

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is, from the client side, you will not be able to load the source of an external domain. You could do it through a server side httpclient call, but NOT from the client side.